# Apollo Nested Query

Tags: apollo

How do I get a value from nested array of object?

Here is my API looks like:

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "code": "ABC123",
  "name": "Abu Bakar Enterprise",
  "speCompanyDetails": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "speCompanyId": 7,
      "registrationType": "2",
      "registrationNo": "12345678",
      "registrationYear": 2005,
      "annualIncome": 100000,
    }
  ]
}
```

My objective is I want to get value for code and name but at the same time I also want to fetch value from speCompanyDetails.annualIncome

Currently my query is similar like this:

```
const SUPPLIER_INFO_QUERY = gql`
query SupplierInfoQuery($mainSuppId: String!) {
    supplierInfo(id: $mainSuppId)
        @rest(path: "services/supplier/api/spe-companies/{args.id}", method: "GET", type: "SupplierInfo") {
            id
            name
            code
            speCompanyDetails
    }
  }
`;
```

But the value for anuualIncome is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

const SUPPLIER_INFO_QUERY = gql
`query SupplierInfoQuery($mainSuppId: String!) {
    supplierInfo(id: $mainSuppId)
        @rest(path: "services/supplier/api/spe-companies/{args.id}", method: "GET", type: "SupplierInfo") {
            id
            name
            code
            speCompanyDetails{ annualIncome }
    }
  }`
;